# What's wrong with having cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0?

Tags: php, nginx, cgi, pathinfo

I'm trying to set up `nginx` for handling `php` requests. [This link](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/#notes) says:

> This guide run fine on php.ini cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 (the default). Some guide insist to change it to cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0 but doing that make PHP_SELF variable broken (not equal to DOCUMENT_URI).

However, [this one](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) doesn't make such warnings:

> Set cgi.fix_pathinfo=0 in php.ini. This causes the PHP interpreter to only try the literal path given and to stop processing if the file is not found.

Judging from [`php` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.fix-pathinfo):

> Setting this to 1 will cause PHP CGI to fix its paths to conform to the spec. A setting of zero causes PHP to behave as before. It is turned on by default. You should fix your scripts to use SCRIPT_FILENAME rather than PATH_TRANSLATED.

It's better stick with the default value.

So, first how to reproduce broken `PHP_SELF` variable? Then, which is it? Is setting `cgi.fix_pathinfo` to 0 a good idea? Or should I choose some other solution?

Comment: Are you running php-cgi anyway? It's somewhat unlikely that nginx is used with anything but php-fpm. Therefore setting this to `1` is obviously not what you wanted.

Comment: Yep, i'm running `php-fpm`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: FPM is not CGI. And the fix_pathinfo flag is only meant to correct the CGI environment under Apache.

Comment: Can you give even more info? Was this flag added specifically for `apache`, or specifically for CGI, or for `apache` + `php` module? What exactly happens with 0, and with 1? Which variables are affected? Can you provide an example of what it did for `apache`/CGI, and an example of what bad it does for `nginx` + `php-fpm`?

Comment: [Is the PHP option 'cgi.fix\_pathinfo' really dangerous with Nginx + PHP-FPM?](http://serverfault.com/q/627903)